# How to kill master process 'rosout'? (will always respawn)

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used '*roscore &*' to launch the ROS master server in a shell script. That might not have been a good idea. After invoking this script I failed to kill process *rosout* as it *always* respawns with a different *pid*. It looks like a watchdog process but I couldn't find one so far. Is there any possibility to kill rosout without having to restart my system?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9337/how-to-kill-master-process-%27rosout%27?-(will-always-respawn)/) by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 960 on 2011-03-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's a python script.
So killall python will work.

If you have other python stuff running:
ps aux|grep roscore and kill the python process with roscore in the name

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on 2011-03-08**:
Yes, you're totally right that my suggestion to use 'killall python' is nasty (I pointed this out, too). I removed my answer to avoid any further confusion and let quality rule over quantity.

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-03-08**:
I strongly recommend against running "killall python".  That will kill every python process on your system.

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2014-04-27**:
killall python no longer works. Is there an elegant solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

roscore itself is set to always keep respawning rosout. You have to kill the roscore process in order to resolve this.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-03-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-03-08**:
The roscore process is a python one.  `ps aux | grep roscore` should get you the pid of the job.

**Comment by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on 2011-03-08**:
There is no such process as 'roscore', at least not on my Ubuntu Maverick + ROS Diamondback. I should have stated the version information earlier.